# Shopify Initial Install Snag

Tags: shopify

I've sort of hit a wall with my initial install of my app into a test store in order to get the demo app up and running.  I've followed the tutorials to the letter, the shopify_app generator generates the initial code with my API Key and Secret Share (It does ask me to replace more files than are listed on the tutorial)  but following that when I run the server and place the subdomain of the test store in to install after about 30 seconds I get an SSL Connection Reset By Peer timeout when the Callback class starts to push back to localhost:3000.  The app shows up as installed in the test store but I can't get it the demo to launch on my end nor get past the intitial install screen.

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: What environment are you developing in? If you're in an ubuntu install there may be a problem with your openssl install, there was a bad version a while back that caused a fair bit of grief

Answer (score 0):

Try working with shopify on a public domain and not on localhost. Do you have a staging environment with a public domain name?
If you do not you can use an ssh reverse proxy on a public domain (aka ssh tunneling)

Answer (score 0):

Shopify runs on https and loads your localhost:3000 via an iframe, which isn't https obviously.

As your browser doesn't load insecure content so you have to tell it to... Here is a discussion for changing that setting:

**Chrome** https://superuser.com/questions/487748/how-to-allow-chrome-browser-to-load-insecure-content

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following services to tunnel your localhost via an SSH connection. 
FREE: https://ngrok.com/
PAID: https://forwardhq.com/